# split string for newlines and for full stops

Tags: r

I would like to use the `stringi` package to split text by sentence.

I have the following sentence:

```
OESOPHAGUS: Everything looks great , no problems. Residual Things's (27-34cm). Everything was washed. Treated with a load of great stuff. 8 various pads were applied.Total of  48 pads given . No immediate complications\nSTOMACH: Normal
```

I would like to split it by sentence as follows:

```
[1] OESOPHAGUS: Everything looks great , no problems. 
[2] Residual Things's (27-34cm)
[3] Everything was washed
[4] Treated with a load of great stuff
[5] 8 various pads were applied
[6] Total of  48 pads given
[7] No immediate complications
[8] STOMACH: Normal
```

However, when I use stringi::stri_split_lines I get:

```
[1] OESOPHAGUS: Everything looks great , no problems. Residual Things's (27-34cm). Everything was washed. Treated with a load of great stuff. 8 various pads were applied.Total of  48 pads given . No immediate complication

[2] STOMACH: Normal
```

I appreciate it is splitting by \n but how can I force it to split by \n or full stop- this must be a common problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the string by both `'\\.|\n'` with following ,

```
dat <- "OESOPHAGUS: Everything looks great , no problems. Residual Things's (27-34cm). Everything was washed. Treated with a load of great stuff. 8 various pads were applied.Total of  48 pads given . No immediate complications\nSTOMACH: Normal"

> strsplit(dat, '\\.|\n') ## base R
> stringi::stri_split_regex(dat, '\\.|\n') ## from stringi package
> stringr::str_split(dat, '\\.|\n') ## from stringr package

[[1]]
[1] "OESOPHAGUS: Everything looks great , no problems"
[2] " Residual Things's (27-34cm)"                    
[3] " Everything was washed"                          
[4] " Treated with a load of great stuff"             
[5] " 8 various pads were applied"                    
[6] "Total of  48 pads given "                        
[7] " No immediate complications"                     
[8] "STOMACH: Normal"
```